# Searching data from multiple tables using Entity framework, Lambda Expressions and Repositorys pattern

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, lambda, repository-pattern

I have the InfoAppointment class, and that class has the foreign key Boat_Id of the Boat class in its table. I would like to show all records of class InfoApontamento that contains a particular Boat. How would I use the foreign key of the boat Class that is in the infoAppointment table to find a particular boat, using lambda expressions and repositorys? Its a One To many relationship

```
public  class InfoAppointment : Entity
{      
    public string Status { get; set; }

    public string Code{ get; set; }

    public string Observation{ get; set; }

    public virtual Boat Boat { get; set; }
}

public class Boat : Entity
{
    public Guid BoatId { get; set; }
    public virtual InfoAppointment  InfoAppointment { get; set; }
}
```

My Example repository

```
public virtual IEnumerable<TEntity> Search(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
    return Dbset.Where(predicate);
}

public class InfoAppointment Repository : Repository<InfoAppointment >, IInfoAppointmentRepository
{
    public InfoAppointmentRepository(RveContext rveContext) : base(rveContext)
    {
    }

    public InfoAppointment GetBoatByName(string boatName)
    {
        // HOW TO GET THE BOATS USING THE FK
    }

    public InfoAppointment GetByCode(string code)
    {
        return Search(c => c.active && !c.excluded && c.Code== code).FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the `name` parameter? Should it be the property of the `InfoAppointment` or the `Boat`? (I don't see such property in any class)

Comment: @Miamy that parameter comes from a dropdown. This dropdown will have a list of boats, when selecting one, this method receives that name and would look for if that boat is in some registry of the InfoAppointment  class. I dont know if my idea is correct

Comment: So `name` is a boat name, am I right?

Comment: @Miamy Yep! I'll edit to make it clearer

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
public InfoAppointment GetByBoatName(string name) // this name is more semantically correct
{
    return Dbset.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Boat != null && c.Boat.Name == name);
}
```

And you don't need to use `Where` before `FirstOrDefault` - the last can accept predicates too, so you can modify `GetByCode` method (or just use `FirstOrDefault` in the `Search` method).

**Edit:**

For the case when a boat has several appointments.
I suggest you really have the next definition:

```
public class Boat : Entity
{
  public Guid BoatId { get; set; }
  public virtual List<InfoAppointment> InfoAppointments { get; set; }
}
```

To return all appointments for the selected boat:

```
public List<InfoAppointment> GetAllByBoatName(string name)
{
  return Boats.First(c => c.Name == name).InfoAppointments.ToList();
}
```

To return one appointment for the selected boat:

```
public InfoAppointment GetOneByBoatName(string name, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> predicate)
{
  return Boats.First(c => c.Name == name).InfoAppointments.FirstOrDefault(predicate);
}
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, my class boat, has a list of InfoAppointment . I even thought about this solution, but I was in doubt as how it would associate the foreign key that is in the InfoAppointment  table, with that name that it received by dropdown

Comment: Please check an updated answer. Also, it would be better if you edit your question to show a real classes relationship to avoid confusing for futher readers.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your relation. Boat class should have a list of InfoAppointment, not single object.
I don't see the case, why you have a boat that can have only one appointment.

However if it's still the case, simply query `(c => c.Boat?.Name == name)`, lazy loading will do the rest.

Edit:
As for defining foreign key in your DB model use `[ForeignKey("BoatId")]` annotation as described here: http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/foreignkey-dataannotations-attribute-in-code-first.aspx

So your InfoAppointment class should look like this:

```
public  class InfoAppointment : Entity
{      
public string Status { get; set; }

public string Code{ get; set; }

public string Observation{ get; set; }

public int BoatId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("BoatId")]
public virtual Boat Boat { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It was my mistake, actually my boat class has a list of InfoAppointment, I ended up confused with other classes that are related to the InfoAppointment class, but specifically my Boat class can have several InfoAppointment

Comment: But how the Entity framework would associate the foreign key that is in the InfoAppointment table, with that name that it received by dropdown? I'm still testing,  I came to think of a solution of this type, but I thought something was missing, because I was in doubt how ORM would associate that name with a foreign key

Answer (score 0):

You can use .Include syntax.

Please refer blog at : http://foreverframe.net/when-use-include-with-entity-framework/

Code:

`var author = context.Boat.Include(a => a.InfoAppointment).FirstOrDefault(c=> c.Boat != null c.Boat.Name == <<name>>);`